# How create a dataframe in R that updates columns automatically when one of the other columns has been changed?

Tags: r, tibble

This is my input

```
    > a<-data.frame(p=c(1:3),q=c(3:5))
    > a
      p q
    1 1 3
    2 2 4
    3 3 5
    > a<-a%>%mutate(r=p*q)
    > a
      p q  r
    1 1 3  3
    2 2 4  8
    3 3 5 15
```

Modifying one the cells

```
   > a$p[1]<-2
   > a
     p q  r
   1 2 3  3
   2 2 4  8
   3 3 5 15
```

a$r[1] has not updated to 2*3=6

I want the output to be:

```
    > a
      p q  r
    1 1 3  6
    2 2 4  8
    3 3 5 15
```

That is I want the value of r to update automatically whenever one of p or q changes.

Comment: You could probably leverage `reactive` if you're willing to go that route. May be some simpler solutions tho. You specified `dplyr` in the tags but it sounds like you're *not* asking about a dplyr data pipeline you'd have to run. By virtue of the fact that you don't want to run code like that I'd say you're actually asking about the data class, which if you use `dplyr` is probably going to be a `tibble`, right? I went ahead and helped you with the tags. You can change it back if you disagree (let us know why though).

Comment: What is going to trigger the other column to change?  If you make that action also trigger an update of the other column (kind of like an observer but not exactly) that would work.    R data frames don't really work like data bases in the sense that some data bases allow you to tie columns together.   The real question is why do you want to retain the redundant information in the new column instead of generating it on the fly when you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to replicate the Excel user experience, right? Editing one cell should update all dependent cells.

Under the covers in Excel -- and what what will eventually be the solution in R -- is a recalculation of all of the possible logically-downstream values. Something will have to trigger it.  In Excel, the trigger is changing a cell or executing the recalculate command.   In the R extension `Shiny` various mouse movements and clicks can do it.

Yes, you could program a method to see if any member of `a$p` or `a$q` had changed, but something would have to trigger that script too.  R doesn't offer a facility that runs all the time, like the piece in you PC that waits for a keyboard input or mouse movement. For most purposes R doesn't take much longer to make every possible calculation than just calculating `a[1,3]` based on a new value of `a[a,1]`.

You can create a function that does all the routine calculations. You can kick it off by typing `recalc()` in the console. No parameters are required. Assign a keyboard shortcut to it and run it after any change to a data object.

```
    recalc <- function() {
      a$r <<- a$p * a$q
      ...
      ...
      TRUE
      }
```

The superassignment operator `<<-` allows you to manipulate the objects in your global environment just as if you were typing the command in the console.  This is not the way you should build functions generally.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be what you're looking for, but here's a simple way to update a single value and have calculated columns update accordingly. I'll use the `data.table` package since it lets you update columns by reference, by row, so you don't have to recalculate the entire column(s) each update.

First I add an attribute to `a` specifying the calculated columns which should be updated. Then I define a function for updating individual values which recognizes that attribute and recalculates the columns as defined.

```
a <- data.frame(p = c(1:3),q = c(3:5))
a <- a %>% mutate(r = p*q, s = p/q - 4)

library(data.table)
setDT(a)
attr(a, 'refresh.cols') <- c(r = 'p*q', s = 'p/q - 4')

df.update <- function(df, row, ...){
  l <- list(...)
  Map(function(x, nm) df[row, eval(parse(text = paste(nm, ':=', x)))]
      , l, names(l))
  df[row, names(attr(a, "refresh.cols")) := 
       lapply(attr(a, "refresh.cols"), function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))]
}
a
#    p q  r         s
# 1: 1 3  3 -3.666667
# 2: 2 4  8 -3.500000
# 3: 3 5 15 -3.400000

a %>% df.update(row = 1, p = 2)
a
#    p q  r         s
# 1: 2 3  6 -3.333333
# 2: 2 4  8 -3.500000
# 3: 3 5 15 -3.400000


a %>% df.update(row = 3, p = 6, q = 7)
a
#    p q  r         s
# 1: 2 3  6 -3.333333
# 2: 2 4  8 -3.500000
# 3: 6 7 42 -3.142857

a %>% df.update(row = 2, p = 9, q = 'p/3 + 1')
a
#    p q  r         s
# 1: 2 3  6 -3.333333
# 2: 9 4 36 -1.750000
# 3: 6 7 42 -3.142857
```